# Is there a way to use react router by viewing a single data from database using Laravel 8?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8

This is my web.php and set the path so I can use react-router. I found this code somewhere by Googling it and it all works. By using this, for example, is "localhost:8000/blog", it all works. but when I use "localhost:8000/blog/1" then the page says it's 404 and I know it's default from Laravel.

This is my **web.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Blog;

Route::view('/{path?}','welcome');
```

This is my **App.js**

```js
import Navbar from './partials/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Blog from './blogs/Blog';
import Student from './students/Student';
import ErrorPage from './ErrorPage';
import Home from './home/Home';
import BlogDetails from './blogs/BlogDetails';
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="example-container">
            <Navbar />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
                    <Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogDetails} />
                    <Route path="/students" component={Student} />
                    <Route component={ErrorPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

So I have this code in my **Blog.js**

```js
import fetchBlog from './fetchBlog';

const Blog = () => {
    const {blogs} = fetchBlog('/api/blog');
    return (
        <div className="blog-container">
            <div className="title-add">
                <h1>Blog Page</h1>
                <h1><a href="/add-blog">Add New Blog</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div className="blog-content">
                {blogs && blogs.map(blog => (
                    <div className="blog-card" key={blog.id}>
                        <h1>{blog.name}</h1>
                        <p>{blog.content}</p>
                        <a href={"/blog/" + blog.id}>View Blogs</a> 
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Blog
```

So the problem is, how do I fix this so I can use the id that will not show the 404 pages of Laravel? When using plain React.js it is working properly.

Comment: `BlogDetails` component is the which should respond to the URL you provided as example, not `Blog`. Maybe you can show that component instead of `Blog`.

Comment: This is working when I'm only using react, but when I use react in laravel project it doesnt work when trying to view particular id.

Comment: You could first try changing `Route::view('/{path?}','welcome');` to `Route::view('/{path}', 'welcome')->where('path', '.*');`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are running an API

1- You need to add a global route like this in **Routes/web.php** (Example)

```
Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\AppController::class, 'index'])->where('any','.*');
```

2- In **Routes/api.php**, this must be a route to match the route you came

```
Route::get('blog/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Blog\BlogController::class, 'show']);
```

Also you need to create route in **Vue** side.
I recommend **Inertia.JS** to you.

Comment: Hi, I'm using React.js. Is it the same with the way you do it in Vue?

Comment: Routes are mandatory in Laravel. Laravel takes requests through a route, returns a response